# Why Visual Studio Code launch 127.0.0.1 instead localhost on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc

I have instaled the .net core 2.1.300-rc1-008673 on Ubuntu 18.04 and Visual Studio Code Version: 1.25.1.

I created a project MVC with Visual Studio Code and when I launched, it runs from  and I got this error: "Your connection is not private. Attackers might be trying to steal your information from 127.0.0.1" But If I change the 127.0.0.1 to localhost everything it is OK.

I don't know why start in 127.0.0.1 if I have this in program.cs:

```
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel(option => 
            {
                option.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
                option.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.UseHttps("localhost.pfx", "lolo");
                });
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

I thought and hoped that the initial URL was .

How do I say to VisualStudioCode run project from localhost ???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is guaranteed to loopback, whereas localhost is subject to dns override.

Comment: so what do I do to run on localhost instead 127.0.0.1 ??

Comment: Https is bound to the address that generated the certificate. If this is a self-generated certificate, regenerate the certificate with the localhost url instead of the IP address.